Cookie not being setted up on webvie
I am trying to insert a cookie programmatically on my WebView. The thing is that I have tried multiple solutions including this one Cookie doesn't work properly in webview in android and still nothing. I am calling the set cookie method before the webview.loadUrl("myUrl"), I have setted a bunch of logs and I get the cookie config correctly, but when I check the console is not there, I have tried removing the secure and HttpOnly and still nothing. Here my code
Configuration of WebView:
fun setWebViewSettings(settings: WebSettings) {
    settings.apply {
        javaScriptEnabled = true
        domStorageEnabled = true
        userAgentString += "BTKApp"
    }
}

Cookie code:
private fun setCookie(url: String, name: String, value: String) {
    val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true)
    val cookie = "$name=$value; domain=$url"
    cookieManager.setCookie(url, cookie)
    cookieManager.flush()
}

